# why are my css background styles being ignored by inline background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have my background image styles in my CSS and the background-image url defined inline. However the CSS styles are getting ignored.. any ideas why?

```css
.myDiv{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv" style="background-image: url('myimage.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: It seems fine here: https://codepen.io/Raddy/pen/ZKmzmg  Have you tried right:0;?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code, so what do you mean when you say it ignores the style?

Comment: Thanks Raddy you have a great point :) ... however when testing on Chrome the styles in my code are getting crossed out... which is weird, however I can se it's working fine in your example.

Comment: I don't get it. Nothing seems wrong with your question

Comment: @jst.sixteen When an issue can't be reproduced we can't help, as the real reason is not available for us, often hidden elsewhere in the code

Comment: I have found the issue, there was a background style that was overriding.. apologies.. all the best J

Comment: That's great. I recommend you delete the question, as the issue weren't reproducible within the posted code and therefore won't bring any value for future users